# Using JSON data to create Collapses

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Hello guys I'm trying to create collapses dynamically from my JSON.

This is how my collapse should look:

[image]

This is part of my JSON that I need for collapses:

```
var cities_visit_list = [
    {
      "city": "Shangahi",
      "date": "05.10.2017",
      "accommodation": "Hotel",
      "accommodation_name": "Hotel King",
      "adress": "BB 23",
      "zip": "555"
    },
    {
      "city_name": "Xian",
      "date": "09.10.2017",
      "accommodation": "Hotel",
      "accommodation_name": "Hotel Warrior",
      "adress": "AA 55",
      "zip": "777"
    }
  ];
```

The number of objects inside array will be different for various users. Now I'm facing two issues: first I don't need all data from my objects and second how to target each collapse with corresponding data.

I've tried to do something like this:

```
    var dropContent = '';
    if (cities_visit_list) {
        var dropData = cities_visit_list;
        $.each(dropData,function(title,data) {
            dropContent = dropContent + '<div class="faqQuestion">';
                dropContent = dropContent + '<h5>' + 'Accomodation ' + (title+1) + '</h5>';
            dropContent = dropContent + '</div>';
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                dropContent = dropContent + '<div class="faqQuestion">';
                    dropContent = dropContent + '<h5>' + val + '</h5>';
                dropContent = dropContent + '</div>';
            });
        });
    }
```

but this way I get wrong HTML structure and I get all data from objects and I need just some of them (type, name, address).

I also thought doing it something like this:

```
    if (cities_visit_list) {
        for (var i = 0; i < proc.cities_visit_list.length; i++) {
            $('.myColumn3').append("<div class='accommodation" + (i+1) + "'><span>Accomodation " + (i+1) + "</span></div>");
        }   
    }
```

and then to manually add content I need through classes, but this seems just as wrong way to approach this.

So my question how can I create my collapses dynamically with corresponding data from JSON, but only the data that I need ?

Here is codepen so you can have a better look at what I'm trying to make: https://codepen.io/Karadjordje/pen/zPrYvX?editors=1010

Comment: Are you able to make changes to the json you get back from whatever server you're getting them from?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I'm stuck with current structure, but I get what you are thinking that would be great :)

Comment: @Zvezdas1989 FYI, those are dropdowns, they're called Collapse or Collapsible.

Comment: Did you mean something like [this?](https://jsfiddle.net/1ja3y6sz/)

Comment: @George Yeah that's it :) I will just need to rewrite es6, I can't use it unfortunately, I'm stuck with concatenating hell of quotes :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've altered your codepen a little to provide you with an example of how to use the JSON data. Is it what you are looking for?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XzMRbO

```js
var cities_visit_list = [
        {
          "city": "Shangahi",
          "date": "05.10.2017",
          "accommodation": "Hotel",
          "accommodation_name": "Hotel King",
          "street_number": "23",
          "zip": "555"
        },
        {
          "city_name": "Xian",
          "date": "09.10.2017",
          "accommodation": "Hotel",
          "accommodation_name": "Hotel Warrior",
          "street_number": "55",
          "zip": "777"
        }
      ];

for (var i = 0; i<cities_visit_list.length; i++) {
    var accommodationDiv = "<div class='faqQuestion'><h5>Accomodation " + (i+1) + "<i class='fa fa-chevron-up rotate'></i></h5> " +
        "<div class='content'>" +
        "<div>" + cities_visit_list[i]['accommodation'] + "</div>" +
            "<div>" + cities_visit_list[i]['accommodation_name'] + "</div>"
    
        "</div>" + 
        "</div>";
    $('.myContent').append(accommodationDiv);
}

$(".faqQuestion").click(function() {
    $(this).find('.content').slideToggle('1000');
    $(this).find('.rotate').toggleClass("down");
});
```

```css
.faqQuestion .rotate {
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.faqQuestion .rotate.down {
    -moz-transform:rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
    transform:rotate(180deg);
}

.content {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="faqQuestion">
    <h5>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, a ?<i class="fa fa-chevron-up rotate"></i>
    </h5>
</div>
<div class="faqAnswer">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam, ex! Rerum ex tempore fugit repudiandae tempora quo id numquam cum?</p>
</div>

<div class="myContent">
    
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah that should be it at least partially,  I'm confused why is dropdown now open by default and by question mark inside closing div > "</div>?"

Comment: You're right about that. The question mark was a typo and the display:none was applied to the wrong element. It's corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better off with a component-oriented structure, like those on React, Vue.js or Angular.

I rewrote your pen using React. See for yourself:

https://codepen.io/fabiodb/pen/zPZwxb

```js
// $(".faqQuestion").click(function() {
//     $(this).next().slideToggle('1000');
//     $(this).find('.rotate').toggleClass("down");
// });

const cities_visit_list = [
        {
          "city": "Shangahi",
          "date": "05.10.2017",
          "accommodation": "Hotel",
          "accommodation_name": "Hotel King",
          "street_number": "23",
          "zip": "555"
        },
        {
          "city_name": "Xian",
          "date": "09.10.2017",
          "accommodation": "Hotel",
          "accommodation_name": "Hotel Warrior",
          "street_number": "55",
          "zip": "777"
        }
      ];


class App extends React.PureComponent {
    state = { active: -1 };

    handleClick = (i) => this.setState(s => ({ active: i === s.active ? -1 : i }));
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Cities:</h1>
                { this.props.cities.map(
                    (c, i) => <City data={c} index={i}
                                  active={ i === this.state.active }
                                  onClick={ () => this.handleClick(i) } />
                ) }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function City({ data, index, active, onClick }) {
    return (
        <div className="faqQuestion">
            <h5 onClick={ onClick }>
                Accomodation { index }
                <i className={"fa fa-chevron-up rotate " + (active ? 'down' : '')}/>
            </h5>
            { active && <CityContent data={data}/> }
        </div>
    )
}

function CityContent({ data }) {
    return (
        <div>
            Name: { data.accommodation_name }
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App cities={ cities_visit_list }/>,
               document.getElementById('myContent'))
```

```css
.faqQuestion .rotate {
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.faqQuestion .rotate.down {
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.faqAnswer {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="myContent">
</div>
```

Comment: I've actually started to learn React recently, although this looks great I still need to figure out basics before I am able to do something like this.